# Synchronization for Memecache Key

Tags: memcached, synchronized

I'm implementing a web server using PHP that uses memcache to store some frequent accessed data. Each request may update one key in memcache. The key is an array and my update will add/remove some  elements to/from the array.

My question is if multiple requests arrive and update the key simultaneously. Does memcache provide any kind of synchronization mechanism.

I search in Google and here, but didn't find much helpful information.

Best, 
Xiaomo

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use cas values in order to do this. The way this works is by requesting the cas number for a key from the server. You then update the value for that key and do set which includes the cas number. The server will then only update the key if the cas has not changed. If it has then you know someone else has updated the data before you did and you can get the value and cas for the key again and retry your update.

*Note: I said here that you do a set and include the cas number. If you look at the binary packet that gets sent this is true, but in most sdk's and in the ASCII protocol there are separate cas functions/commands. You want to use these instead of set functions/operations when doing your update.

To do a cas in the ASCII protocol see here:
http://code.sixapart.com/svn/memcached/trunk/server/doc/protocol.txt